# Using if-else in where clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to implement in the `where` clause.

I tried in `case` statement but between cannot be used in `case` statement

```
where 
    if  start_mth < end_mth
        mth_no between start_mth and end_mth
    else start_mth > end_mth
        mth_no between start_mth and 12
                      or
        mth_no between 1 and end_mth
```

Comment: looks like you are condition is not correct,as it uses the same start_mth<end_mth in both the cases

Comment: You can't use else with a condition "else start_mth>end_mth" is wrong anyway.

Comment: If you really need an "if-else", then you should use start_mth >= end_mth. Because if you are not using it, then the = will missing and the query will break if the values are equal. If you don't need it, then you need an "if-else if" and not an "if-else"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where 
((start_mth<end_mth) and (mth_no   between start_mth and end_mth)) or
((start_mth>end_mth) and ((mth_no  between start_mth and 12) or (mth_no   between  1 and end_mth)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 
(start_mth < end_mth AND mth_no BETWEEN start_mth and end_mth)
OR
(start_mth >= end_mth AND 
     (mth_no  BETWEEN start_mth AND 12 
         OR mth_no BETWEEN 1 AND end_mth))
```